# Set Range variable too long

Tags: excel, variables, vba

I have the below code that can work but in its current format it gives a Run Time error'1004. I am sure it is because the range i am setting is to long. It works if I shorten it. How can this be made to work?
I have seen similar questions but not one that answers my particular request.

I want to run this on on Column L and then every 7th column after that.

```
Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
Set A = Range("L:L,S:S,Z:Z,AG:AG,AN:AN,AU:AU,BB:BB,BI:BI,BP:BP,BW:BW,CD:CD,CK:CK,CR:CR,CY:CY,DF:DF,DM:DM,DT:DT,EA:EA,EH:EH,EO:EO,EV:EV,FC:FC,FJ:FJ,FQ:FQ,FX:FX,GE:GE,GL:GL,GS:GS,GZ:GZ,HG:HG,HN:HN,HU:HU,IB:IB,II:II,IP:IP,IW:IW,JD:JD,JK:JK,JR:JR,JY:JY,KF:KF,KM:KM,KT:KT,LA:LA,LH:LH,IP:IP,IW:IW,JD:JD,JK:JK,JR:JR,JY:JY,KF:KF,KM:KM,KT:KT,LA:LA,LH:LH")
Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each r In Inte
        If r.Offset(0, -1).Value = "" Then
        r.Offset(0, -1).Value = Now()
        End If
    Next r
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

First time asking a question but this site has helped me so much.
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Split up setting A into multiple operations with Union.

```
Set A = Range("L:L,S:S,Z:Z,AG:AG,AN:AN,AU:AU,BB:BB,BI:BI,BP:BP,BW:BW")
Set A = Union(A, Range("CD:CD,CK:CK,CR:CR,CY:CY,DF:DF,DM:DM,DT:DT,EA:EA,EH:EH,EO:EO,EV:EV"))
Set A = Union(A, Range("FC:FC,FJ:FJ,FQ:FQ,FX:FX,GE:GE,GL:GL,GS:GS,GZ:GZ,HG:HG,HN:HN,HU:HU,IB:IB,II:II"))
Set A = Union(A, Range("IP:IP,IW:IW,JD:JD,JK:JK,JR:JR,JY:JY,KF:KF,KM:KM,KT:KT,LA:LA,LH:LH,IP:IP,IW:IW"))
Set A = Union(A, Range("JD:JD,JK:JK,JR:JR,JY:JY,KF:KF,KM:KM,KT:KT,LA:LA,LH:LH"))
```

If the stagger is consistent, it may be easier to find Target's column.

```
for each r in target
    if r.column > 11 and (r.column mod 7) = 5 then
        If r.Offset(0, -1).Value = "" Then
            r.Offset(0, -1).Value = Now()
        End If
    end if
next r
```

Comment: Worked a treat! Thank you, thank you. I tried unions but did not know it could be arranged like that.

Comment: Personally, I think the alternative method with column mod 7 is a little cleaner.

Comment: Agree. I knew there would be a way to do it but above my skill set at this stage.